# Just upgraded Mavericks server to 10.9.2 and my virtual hosts partially work

Tags: macos, websites

Just upgraded Mavericks server to 10.9.2 and my virtual hosts partially work. We have four... wiki.blahh.org, crm.blahh.org, server.blahh.org and helpdesk.blahh.org. All of the web files are on the server and all A name records in DNS point to server.blahh.org's IP address... 192.168.1.5. wiki and cdm resolve properly and show the proper website, server.blahh.org shows the default (which is also correct) but help desk.blahh.org also shows the default server page and doesn't show the proper website.

What is going on?

All of the virtual host directives look okay but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

First, check permissions on everything.

Are the vhost directives all in one file or different files in the vhost directory?

Second, could we have a look at the virtual host directives?